# After offering salah I always feel something is release from my body... what could be is that?

Tags: salat

After offering my Salah I always feel something is release from my body I want to find out what could be is that? And before Salah I feel so heavy and confused whether I should go for Salah to finish out my work first.

Comment: This could be moved to [cogsci.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quran, the word of Allah says Salat (or generally any kind of remembering Allah) bring relaxation for soul of human:

> الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَتَطْمَئِنُّ قُلُوبُهُم بِذِكْرِ‌ اللَّـهِ ۗ أَلَا
>   بِذِكْرِ‌ اللَّـهِ تَطْمَئِنُّ الْقُلُوبُ
>
> Those who have believed and whose hearts are assured by the
>   remembrance of Allah. Unquestionably, by the remembrance of Allah
>   hearts are assured." http://tanzil.net/#13:28

It can be due to this relaxation and assurance.